# Web Services written using SOAP

Tags: xml, json, soap

If you are creating client application and your server implementation is done with SOAP then you have to use SOAP in client side. How valid is this ??? and how do you determine the protocol used in writing the server implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

The provider of the SOAP WebService will in most cases provide a WSDL file specifying the interface and the endpoint offered. For instance SOAP over HTTP or SOAP over JMS.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you have coded on your own or not because the question is too naive.

So to answer your question part 1.
Yes if server side it is SOAP then we have to adhere with SOAP protocol and write our client for SOAP because SOAP is a protocol used for exchanging information. So client has to send what server is expecting.

To answer your second question
For communication with server and for that matter writing your client, you will be given WSDl or URL to the WSDL.
So if WSDl is given then it is nothing but SOAP.